# Equivalent Map.Compute in C#

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to convert some code from `java` to `C#` but I´m stuck with this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); // converted to Dictionary<int, int>
for (int i : elements)//converted to  foreach (int i in elements)
    map.compute(i, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v+1)
```

What is the equivalent If I'm doing it with a dictionary in `C#`?

Comment: NB, in Java this can be more easily written as `map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: `map.TryGetValue(k, out var v) ? v + 1 : 1;` where `map` is now C# `Dictionary`

Comment: @itsme86 Dcount.Compute(i, (k, v) => v == null ? 1 : v + 1); my real code is the same as geekforgeeks..

Comment: What is the result of this operation?  Does it return a value, a collection of values, or does it mutate the map?

Comment: @Flydog57 is to trying to return a collection of values

Comment: You probably want to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and it's more aptly named [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-, it appears that it mutates the map.  I think you will need to edit your question showing and initial `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that contains some values, and then how you'd call the function you want and what the result might end up with.  As it stands, I don't understand the explanation on the Oracle site.  In some cases, it appears to mutate the map (returning nothing), however, in one case, it returns a null.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thx, It was Edit !!

Comment: @Flydog57 I believe it returns null if the remapping function you pass returns null, which means the map will no longer have an entry for the key if it had one to begin with.

Comment: `Map<Integer,Integer> != Dictionary<int,int>`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils why it is not is a Equivalent??  Map<Integer,Integer> != Dictionary<int,int>???

Comment: Because `Integer`s are reference types and an `int` is a primitive value type. In your example, you check your value against `null` but an `int` can never by `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an exact equivalent that exists so it may come down to implementing it yourself to some degree. If you're looking for a solution that looks and feels the same, you can add an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to `Dictionary<K,V>`.

There's sufficient differences between these languages to require a bit of hand waiving but, to get to the gist of it, this should suffice as a starting point.

`Compute` doesn't exist on the C# `Dictionary` so you can add it. Ideally, for an "*equivalent*", you'd want to ensure it covers all the cases as the original, not just this particular case (IMHO). I don't claim that the following does but you can ensure yours does by investigating the source code for `compute` in your Java version. (this is what I came up with looking over [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-); I could be off).

```
// You can easily add to the Dictionary<K, V> implementation; SWEET!
public static class DictExtensions
{
    public static V Compute<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dict, K key, Func<K, V, V> func) 
    {
        // if no func given, throw.
        if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));
        // if no mapping, return null.
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) return default;
        // get the new value from func.
        var result = func(key, value);
        if (result == null)
        {
            // if the mapping exists but func => null,
            // remove the mapping and return null.
            dict.Remove(key);
            return default;
        }
        // mapping exists and func returned a non-null value.
        // set and return the new value
        dict[key] = result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, after adding a correct `using` statement to the code you'd like to use `Compute` in, use it like you expect: `map.Compute(i, (k, v) => (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);`

Comment: In Java, also returns value to the Func if no mapping, so it's better to do it like Java and instead of `if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) return default;` just write `dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)` and don't return and let the user choose. What you write is equivalent to _computeIfPresent_

Comment: @Alger, good catch. I'll try to get it updated soon.